# Knowing the current Revision of a file or the project/solution for AnkhSVN

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, ankhsvn

How can I view the current revision number of a particular file from Visual Studio or directly from Explorer under SVN Source control? I am using AnkhSVN as the client.

Also, is it possible to know the revision number when the project/solution was last updated from server and changes to some of its files have been made thereafter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install TortoiseSVN to have the integration of SVN in Explorer (File explorer i assume?).

Comment: Your second part of the question is not that simple. The first part: The revision number of the current files (take look via TortoiseSVN) that's the revision a file/directory have been changed the last time...The update timepoint can't be calculated by that. What you can do in TortoiseSVN is to use "Check for Modification" and use the "Repository" button...

Answer (score 3):

1. use the string $Rev$ in your source file, e.g.

   ```
   string revision = "$Rev$".Replace("$", "");
   ```
2. in solution explorer right click on that source file and select Subversion/Subversion properties
3. Add Property svn:keywords and enable "Rev".

Voilà: on every commit "$Rev$" is replaced with the new svn revision.

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to know the revision number when the project/solution was last updated from server and changes to some of its files have been made

Because you have TortoiseSVN installed, check Properties of the root-folder, Subversion tab. "Revision" and "Last commit" are answers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use AnkhSVN 2.6 and not planning to switch over to anything else.

Found a development library for VS2015 and 2.X

Reference is mensioned on the AnkhSVN website,

https://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/

*"SharpSvn is a binding of the Subversion Client API for .Net 2.0-4.0+ applications contained within a set of xcopy-deployable dll's. Notable users of this api are"*

short tutorial

https://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/docs/walkthrough.htm

Binaries can be downloaded at

https://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpcvslib/

Gotta try this one day.. for now, I open "Solution History", find the revision number of my Setup project and attach that number to my main version
number manually.